# Cannot resolve symbol 'SpotsDialog'

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I am getting error in implementing SpotsDialog. My whole code is appearing correct but "SpotsDialog" shows in red and the error is: package SpotsDialog does not exist
I am facing problem whenever I run the app.

**I had also given implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@arr' under dependencies but dont know its imported or not properly**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.content.DialogInterface;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.text.TextUtils;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.delegates.delegatesapp.User.User;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;

import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnSignIn, btnRegister;
    LinearLayout rootLayout;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase db;
    DatabaseReference users;
    AlertDialog waiting_dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = db.getReference("users");

        btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        btnRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        rootLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showRegisterDialog();
            }
        });

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showLoginDialog();
            }
        });

        waiting_dialog = new SpotsDialog.Builder()
                .setContext(this)
                .setMessage(R.string.app_name)
                .setCancellable(false)
                .build();

    }
```

build.Gradle(app) file below

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'

}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.delegates.delegatesapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs' , include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:17.0.0'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:18.0.1'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:19.0.0'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:17.0.0'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:20.0.0'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.2'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:17.0.0'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:17.0.0'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:20.0.1'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:18.1.2'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'

    //Add Library
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@arr'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:'
}
```

build.gradle(DelegatesApp)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not seeing SpotsDialog in your import statements..are you able to find that class in your project?

if yes then add it in your import statements..

if no then maybe library not properly imported..have you added jcenter() in gradle file and synched your project?

**Update based on comment-**

Put your cursor on "SpotsDialog" text where it shows in red and press **Alt + Enter**.Check if you get an option to import?

If not,then **double press Shift** and you get option to search file in project.Check if "SpotsDialog" file exists in your project?

If not,post your gradle file in question!

**Update 2**

Spelling of aar is wrong in your gradle file-

Change

```
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@arr'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
```

Comment: yes there is not any import statement in my class. Please tell me how can i do that. jcenter() is already added and dependencies is also written but its not imported in my class. How can i import that statements... Please help me....

Comment: After Alt+Enter is says to create class or create inner class 'SpotsDialog'. And also i cant find any file after pressing Shift button twice. Sir i had posted gradle file please check.

Comment: @Amiya Add `import dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog` to your imports..and check if class able to find it!

Comment: no it did not worked as dmax shows in red. if you can give time please help me on hangout.

Comment: @Amiya ok..are you able to successfully sync your gradle files?..i see     `implementation 'com.android.support:design:'` in your gradle file which is missing version number

Comment: No sir whenever i add version number it turns red in both design and cardview both

Comment: @Amiya Updated my answer..check Update 2

Comment: Thank you sir for your time & help. And at the same time sorry for your time waste as it was such a silly mistake.... Thank you so much

Comment: @Amiya If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Please help me with few problems https://stackoverflow.com/q/64912363/14485264